# Emacs: Convert Unicode Bullets to " * "

Tags: emacs

No luck finding this answer anywhere! I have a text file with many bullets and dashes represented by Unicode(?) characters such as:

```
\342\200\224 All module...
\342\227\217 Introductory presentations...
\342\200\224 The assistant...
```

I need to convert these to markdown bullets " * ". I've tried the following commands to no avail:

`replace-string "\342\200\224" RET "* " RET`
`replace-regex \\u342\200\\224 RET * RET`

..and many variants. Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should try to get the coding system of the file recognized, so they appear in Emacs as the proper characters, not as octal sequences.  `C-x RET r` will help here, and most likely you want one of the `utf-8` coding systems.

Once the characters are showing up in Emacs, you can copy one into the kill buffer and yank it when performing the replace command such as `M-%`.

Comment: I'll try that out and mark as an answer soon. This looks like a great item to add to my import workflow.